# Assign MySQL @rowid as value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing table with lot of rows (around 10k rows) with two columns as primary keys as it is acting as middle table of many-to-many relation between two other table.

For new requirements, I need to assign add new column (say `id`) which must be primary key with auto increment values. I ran following queries:

```
ALTER TABLE  `momento_distribution` ADD  `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL FIRST;
ALTER TABLE  `momento_distribution` DROP PRIMARY KEY , ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` );
```

First query run successfully but second query generated following error:

```
1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Reason is obvious, new column `id` got 0 as default value and Primary key can't have duplicate values.

Now before I can run second query, I need to set incremental value for new column like 1,2,3...

In Oracle, I know, this can be done through rowid. MySQL also have its equivalent @rowid. Can someone please suggest a query to set @rowid as column value for column `id`?

**Please Note: This had to be done through query as I can't change 10000 rows manually.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same question asked by same user differently. Refer to that question.

[MySQL 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary/12189846#12189846)

In short,
1. Remove existing FK
2. Remove existing PK
3. Run your first query as

```
ALTER TABLE  `momento_distribution` ADD  `id` INT( 11 ) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL FIRST;
```

which will also assign unique number without depending on @rowid
4. Add FK to earlier columns, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set it to AUTO_INCREMENT at the same time, that will populate it;

```
ALTER TABLE momento_distribution 
  ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/058f2/2).

EDIT: If you have an existing primary key, you'll need to drop that at the same time;

```
ALTER TABLE momento_distribution 
  DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

Comment: Thanks @Joachim. +1 for SQL Fiddle demo (I knew JS Fiddle but not SQLFiddle). This gives me confidence. Unfortunately I left office for the day. Waiting eagerly to test that on me table. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry @Joachim but it will not work. I just added primary key to your table like **name VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY** and it failed. In my case too, I already have existing Primary key.

Comment: Edited with a statement that replaces the existing primary key. The SQLFiddle table was just an example table to show how the alter table worked, what you want is the statement above; `ALTER TABLE momento_distribution 
  DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;`