# How to make automatic assignment of id values in the form of creating an item

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have form of creating shop item which was generated by Gii.

So i myself must to enter id value. But I need to get rid of this field, and make an assignment automatically.

For auto assignment creating and updating time, i just adding this function in my module

```
  public function behaviors() {
    return [
      TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
  }
```

How can i do this for id value?

**UPD**

Rules:

```
  public function rules() {
    return [
      [['category_id', 'title', 'desc', 'price', ], 'required'],
      [['id', 'category_id', 'price', 'in_stock', 'discount', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
      [['desc', 'options', 'photos'], 'string'],
      [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
    ];
  }
```

**UPD 2**

```
<?php

namespace backend\modules\shop\controllers;

use backend\modules\shop\models\ShopCategories;
use Yii;
use backend\modules\shop\models\ShopItems;
use backend\modules\shop\models\ShopItemsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * ItemsController implements the CRUD actions for ShopItems model.
 */
class ItemsController extends Controller {

  public function behaviors() {
    return [
      'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
          'delete' => ['post'],
        ],
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Lists all ShopItems models.
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new ShopItemsSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $this->render('index', [
      'searchModel' => $searchModel,
      'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Displays a single ShopItems model.
   * @param integer $id
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionView($id) {
    return $this->render('view', [
      'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Creates a new ShopItems model.
   * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new ShopItems();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
      return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'category' => ShopCategories::find()->all()
      ]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Updates an existing ShopItems model.
   * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @param integer $id
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
      return $this->render('update', [
      'model' => $model,
      'category' => ShopCategories::find()->all()
      ]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Deletes an existing ShopItems model.
   * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
   * @param integer $id
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionDelete($id) {
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
  }

    /**
     * Finds the ShopItems model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return ShopItems the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id) {
      if (($model = ShopItems::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
      } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly you want to assign it?

Comment: @arogachev very simple. 1, 2, 3... Every next creating automatic assign  next number. For example, default registration at advanced app assign previous id + 1. But i check that module and don't understand how it occurs. :(

Comment: Why not simply declare this column as primary key in database and remove it from validation in model?

Comment: @arogachev my id cullumn already have primary key. First creating assigned id = 0. Second throw exception course that try assign id=0, and id like it already exist.

Comment: Show model validation rules and the code where you are trying to assign it.

Comment: @arogachev Added rules. "code where you are trying to assign" - what do you mean? _form.php?

Comment: @arogachev I can add screenshot from phpMyAdmin, to ensure correctness. But it has russian language, and idk how change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include attributes that are managed automatically or by programmer in model validation rules. Validation make sense only for user entered data.

Remove `id` from that line and everything should be OK:

```
 [['id', 'category_id', 'price', 'in_stock', 'discount', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
```

`created_at` and `updated_at` are also redundant because they don't depend on user, so this is enough:

```
 [['category_id', 'price', 'in_stock', 'discount'], 'integer'],
```

**Update:**

After deeper investigation we found that primary key didn't have auto increment. After executing this query problem disappeared:

```
ALTER TABLE `shop_items`
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Credits for **Miroslav's** answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary).