# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' - Database glitched?

Tags: mysql

I keep getting "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'" when running the following SQL command from a PHP script:

```
INSERT INTO Backgrounds (user, url)
VALUES ('$user', '$bgrequest')
```

And here is the code that generates the table below. The first insert works, but all subsequent requests do not. I have tried deleting the table and recreating, still no luck. Also when I insert a row from phpmyadmin, it works and increments without issue. For some reason it just doesn't seem to autoincrement when running the command from a PHP script...

```
CREATE TABLE  `freestylefriday`.`Backgrounds` (  
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  
`user` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,  
`url` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL  
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Such a simple table and request... driving me crazy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary)

Comment: have you tried to create the table the old way?  ... CREATE TABLE `freestylefriday`.`Backgrounds`
(
id  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`url` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL  
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: Thanks Ed, that did the trick!