# MySQL Error: Duplicate entry 'xxx' for Primary Key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have table MySQL with Primary Key Composed of 2 fields, as below

[image: Script showing Primary Key]

Already existing records in the table are:

[image: Existing Records]

The INSERT query I am issuing is:

[image: The Query]

When I run the query:

```
INSERT INTO `case_data` 
VALUES ('WCD/2016/1000017', 2, '2016-09-29', 'WCD',***********************
```

The error message displayed is:

> [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry 'WCD/2016/1000017' for key 'PRIMARY'

Am I violating the Primary Key constraint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only add unique string in Primary key column. here "WCD/2016/1000017" is already extist in table, so you cannot add same string in table for primary key column.

Comment: Yes, you violating the primary key contraint.

Comment: @Vivek: If I were to change the value '**WCD/2016/1000017**' to something else, why would I need to use Composite Key?

Comment: You may take one more column "id" with auto increment. this may be solve your problem.

Comment: Agreed. But what's wrong with manually incrementing the '**Iteration**' field? That is the very concept of Composite Key: You can keep all fields of the Key same, and change only one field of the key.

Comment: may be you can find something from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179770/mysql-1062-duplicate-entry-0-for-key-primary#answer-12179783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the primary key values of a row you are trying to insert already exist in a table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM case_data
WHERE caseno = 'WCD/2016/1000017' AND iteration = 2;
```

If it returns `0` then you will not violate the PK constraint and are safe to insert the row you wish (assuming there are no additional checks, triggers, constraints). Otherwise it will return `1` which means that you already have a row with values in those columns, thus you would violate uniqueness of the row which is not allowed.

When it returns `0` just issue an `INSERT` command. Also, remember to specify your column tables within the statement to make sure every value from your `VALUES` is being put within the right column of your destination table:

```
INSERT INTO case_data (caseno, iteration, casedate, casetype)
VALUES ('WCD/2016/1000017', 2, '2016-09-29', 'WCD');
```

Avoid using backticks around your column and table names if they don't contain alternative characters like commas or spaces. This will make your code more readable and definitely speed up your writing time.

Comment: I tried the SELECT query you suggested, and it returns 0. But still I am not able to insert a row with the above INSERT query.

Comment: There must be something else preventing you from doing the INSERT imho. Check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa8ec

Comment: I clicked "Build Schema" below first box and then clicked "Run SQL" below the second box. Nothing showed up in second box. Sorry, but I have never used **SQL Fiddle** website.

Comment: Well, it issued CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. In the second box you can type `SELECT * FROM case_data` to see that everything works, and no error was there while inserting

Comment: Kamil. You were right. The problem with a 3rd level trigger. Problem solved. Thankyou.